# How to create an Expo EAS iOS internal distribution build not an iOS App Store build with bare workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

I've added native code to my `Expo 48` project. I'm able to build a production/release version of my app to upload to the app store manually from XCode/Android Studio. However, I need to build an internal/preview version with ad hoc provisioning using `EAS` so I can distribute it to internal QA for testing.

"When you're ready to ship your app, you can build it with EAS Build the same as you were building it before adding custom native code. Alternatively, you can archive and sign it locally. Unsurprisingly, we recommend EAS Build!"

This is the command I used to create an internal build before switching to bare workflow, it looks at `eas.json` for the configuration for the preview/internal build,
`eas build --platform ios --profile internal --non-interactive --json`.

How can I do the same thing now and successfully build when I've added native code. My CI/CD suit and EAS build keeps failing with the following error.

```
Failed to set up credentials.
You're in non-interactive mode. EAS CLI couldn't find any credentials suitable for internal distribution. Run this command again in interactive mode.
    Error: build command failed.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

PS: It works fine on Android but is failing on iOS.

Thanks in advance!

https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/

Comment: Do you have an eas.json file at the root of your expo app? That error looks like you dont have an internal distribution profile set up.

Comment: I do. I can build right now but after switching to managed workflow it's ignoring `eas.json` and looking for the configuration from native files is my understanding.

Comment: I have the same problem..! Did you find a way to let this work?